# Can't scrape the data while selecting drop down boxes value using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am using `BeautifulSoup` to scrape the data from the website https://oxygen.digiavidity.com/?fbclid=IwAR3d_HtQPWni0lyHOMQOdokZGg3J7acwYc80EOFX7g8XYHloC550R5BtO94  .

But if I select a particular district from the  `District` drop-down box to get all the `Suppliers name(in bold)` and `contacts` from the particular district, keeping the other two dropdown boxes as default then I'm not able to fetch the required data.

suppose I'm select the drop-down boxes as :
[image]

Here is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://oxygen.digiavidity.com/? 
       fbclid=IwAR3d_HtQPWni0lyHOMQOdokZGg3J7acwYc80EOFX7g8XYHloC550R5BtO94"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "lxml")

x=soup.find_all('div',class_='list-group')
for val in x:
   name=val.find('h5',class_='mb-1').text
   contact=val.find('p').text
   print(name)
   print(contact)
```

Someone, please help me. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to scrape this website since the data is loaded fom an api. You can get the data with `requests` and parse the json as a dictionary with `response.json()`. Then you can load it in `pandas` for example.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; Trident/6.0; Touch)',
    'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
}

response = requests.post('https://oxygen.digiavidity.com/ViewData/All', headers=headers)
df = pd.DataFrame(response.json())
```

Result `df.head()`:

|  | _id | Ident | District | Area_Name | Supplier_Name | Supplier_Contact | Updated_date | Updated_Time | Fresh_Cylinder_Availability | Oxygen_Refilling | Additional_Information | Delivery_Range | SPOC | Availability_Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 60b91659c21655ec6eac3bf6 | 1 | Kolkata | Kolkata | Swarnabha Dey | 9038399847 | 3-June-2021 | 8:31 PM | Yes | No | photo identity proof and prescription required | All over West Bengal | Ranita | nan |
| 1 | 60b91659c21655ec6eac3bf7 | 2 | Bankura | Bankura | Shreyasi(Volunteer) | 7866855988 | 3-Jun-2021 | 12:57 PM | Yes | Yes | photo identity proof and prescription required | Bankura | Ranita | immediate refilling will be done only in town. Rest will take some time or contacts will be shared |
| 2 | 60b91659c21655ec6eac3bf8 | 3 | Bankura | Maliyaja, Bankura | Baishali Tiwari | 9831935524 | 20-May-2021 | 8:14:00 AM | No | No | nan | Bankura | Chirantan | Delivering cylinders only to hospitals |
| 3 | 60b91659c21655ec6eac3bf9 | 4 | Birbhum | Rampurhat | Deb Bikram Dutta, Tarun Dutta (Don't call before 10am) | 9434132232 | 3-Jun-2021 | 1:00:00 PM | Yes | Yes | Prescription and Aadhar card required | Rampurhat | Ranita | Both fresh cylinder and refilling available |
| 4 | 60b9165ac21655ec6eac3bfa | 5 | Birbhum | Bolpur | Ani | 7029177504 | 3-Jun-2021 | 13:03:00 | Yes | Yes | Whatsapp him the patient details to his number | Bolpur | Ranita | Both fresh cylinder and refilling available |

You can filter by district like this: `df[df['District'] == 'Birbhum']`

Comment: How to print the data by omitting the column `_id` ? @RJAdriaansen

Comment: `df = df.drop(columns=['_id'])`